# How can I re-use token (jwt) in other java microservices (spring)?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I have a login microservice with spring boot and JWT. I mean that I have an endpoint like this:

URI: /login
Method: Post

Request:

```
{
  username: "example",
  password: "example"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  token: "cwjc4k3jn2kjn45kmj"
}
```

How can I make my other microservices recognize this token and that there is an open session? In Spring Framework with JWT

Comment: You would need a authentication service acts as a gateway. All requests wil go through the gateway and after authentication the requests need to be routed to different services. [link](https://medium.com/@mool.smreeti/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-and-spring-security-6e10155d9db0) Check this one

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. If you can add your answer in this question to accept it.

Comment: Use OpenID/OAuth2.0. You need an Identity Provider (e.g. Keycloak, AWS Cognito, ...) and a OAuth2.0 library/framework (e.g. spring-security-oauth-resource-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an authentication service acts as a gateway. All requests wil go through the gateway and after authentication the requests need to be routed to different services. [Example](https://medium.com/@mool.smreeti/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-and-spring-security-6e10155d9db0)